# When using lighttpd, mod_magnet and lua, can I access the raw request headers?

Tags: lua, lighttpd

For a PoC I'm building I need to emulate the TRACE method in lighttpd. Using mod_magnet and lua I can reconstruct the request using the method/version/headers functions. But by doing so, the header order, case etc will be changed from the original.

Is it possible to improve upon this by accessing the raw headers, as received? Or is there a better way to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.lighttpd.net/DebugVariables

`debug.log-request-header = "enable"`

If you need access to the raw bytes as lighttpd processes them, then you will need to modify the lighttpd source code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Does this just push the header to the logs, or will this also expose it within LUA? And if so, how do I access it?

Comment: `debug.log-request-header = "enable"` writes trace to the error log.  Iterating over the headers in lua will give you the order in which they were received, but the contents will have been normalized (and, if necessary, line-unwrapped and combined).  See also [server.http-parseopts](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Server_http-parseoptsDetails)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used the mod_magnet module plus LUA, and whilst not perfect, it is actually close enough not to matter. Et voilla, a TRACE response:

```
lighty.header["Content-Type"] = "message/http" 
lighty.r.resp_body.add(lighty.r.req_attr["request.method"] .. " " .. lighty.r.req_attr["request.orig-uri"] .. " HTTP/1.1\n")
for k, v in pairs(lighty.r.req_header) do
    lighty.r.resp_body.add( k .. ": " .. v .. "\n")
end
lighty.r.resp_body.add( "\n" )
return 200
```